# Sharepoint 2013: SPweb.Groups.GetByName(groupName) throwing exception

Tags: development, .net

I am trying to create a new SharePoint group programmatically (using .Net), for this I am using the following C# code

```
            //greate group with no users:

            web.SiteGroups.Add(groupName, groupOwner, null, description);
            //Parameters are defined earlier in the code such as:
            //   string groupName
            //   SPUser groupOwner
            //   string description

            web.Update();
            SPGroup newGroup = web.Groups.GetByName(groupName);
```

The creation works well but when I try to access the group an exception is thrown saying "Group cannot be found." What is the reason that the group can not be found and how can I fix this (I need to access the group for my further code)? If I check on the SharePoint under People and Groups the group is there.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I'm guessing it's because you are using old SPWeb object which doesn't have new group in it's properties. Dispose old object and create new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :  SPGroup oGroup = web.SiteGroups["Original_Name"];

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. That is what I had originally with the same result that an exception was thrown.

Comment: Please check waht following methods return :private  bool GroupExistsInWebSite(SPWeb web, string name)
{
    return web.Groups.OfType<SPGroup>().Count(g => g.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) > 0;
}
private bool GroupExistsInSiteCollection(SPWeb web, string name)
{
    return web.SiteGroups.OfType<SPGroup>().Count(g => g.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) > 0;
}

Comment: This web.SiteGroups[groupName]; works for me. web.Groups[groupName] was throwing exception Group cannot be found

Comment: Thanks that helped, I must have mist out on this part. It is working for me now as well.